# telerik:RadAsyncUpload is not firing event OnFileUploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the RadAsyncUpload. When I have uploaded a file I am expecting the `OnFileUploaded` event to occur, but it is firing when I am clicking the submit button. Now two events - one for upload and the other for the submit button - are firing, one after the other.

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="RadAsyncUpload1" runat="server" EnableInlineProgress="true" UploadedFilesRendering="BelowFileInput" 
   HideFileInput="true" ClientIDMode="AutoID" MultipleFileSelection="Disabled"
   Localization-Select="Choose File" Width="100%" MaxFileInputsCount="1" OnFileUploaded="rauploadCSVFile_OnFileUploaded">
</telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
<telerik:RadButton ID="rbtnSubmit" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="rbtnSubmit_OnClick">
</telerik:RadButton>
```

How can I make `RadAsyncUpload` fire the event when I have uploaded a file?

Answer (score 4):

OnFileUploaded will be executed on PostBack. That's why it doesn't react when you choose a file, but reacts on the Submit button being clicked.

I encountered a similar problem recently, here's how I solved it:

First of all, if you want `RadAsyncUpload` to react to every file you choose to upload, you need to add the `OnClientFilesUploaded` to `telerik:RadAsyncUpload`, where you point to a JavaScript function. For example...

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="RadAsyncUpload1" ... OnClientFileUploaded="OnRadAsyncUpload1ClientAction"> ...
</telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
```

And ofcourse, add your function to your scripts:

```
function OnRadAsyncUpload1ClientAction(source, args)
{
    __doPostBack('RadAsyncUpload1', args);
}
```

It worked for me. I hope it'll work for you.

Comment: do not add OnRadAsyncUpload1ClientAction inside jquery Document.load ($(function () ) of course. thank you.